# HTTP server on EC2 instance unreachable after a few minutes

Tags: amazon-web-services

- I have a running instance on the Linux 2 AMI.
- I have a default VPC and network interface.
- Security groups taken care of, even opened all traffic and still got nothing.
- There is an Internet Gateway
- Routes are open on the VPC
- The server is running
- nginx is running
- Once the instance is initiated and installed, all of this is ready

I can reach the http website the first 2-3 minutes, then it is unreacheable.

No idea why, everything else still running, can still ssh into the server, but http port 80 not running.

I opened everything from `iptables`, still nothing.

If I reboot the server, I get a minute where I can reach the server via http, but then a minute later its the same again.

I can reach http if I use `$ wget http://localhost`

So I think it is probably something from the EC2 control panel, not the instance itself.

I tried on new instances too.

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Have you checked the nginx logs? Have you checked dmesg for out of memory errors?

Comment: nothing on the logs, as if no attempt to access was even made,
for the dmesg that's a new one for me, a bit higher than my level but i will study it now i know it exists
for the memory i tried the free command, got enough memory
and on dmesg everything is green so i assume everything is alright there too

Comment: So nginx is dying but nothing is logging it? Are you sure its not getting overlooked? `journalctl -u nginx` will show the journal logs.

Comment: it isn't dying, it is still working on http://localhost, the service is running, 

life is good, but i bet its either an error with AWS EC2 it self or something i missed in their configs

Comment: Check the security group of the instance

Comment: all traffic allowed inbound and out bound, 

i've been stuck here since 4 days now, usually got an ego to figure it out on my own, but i gave up and decided to post a question

Comment: Yeah, idk. it's very strange that nginx would work briefly from remote and then only work from localhost. definitely a misconfiguration somewhere, but that kind of issue doesn't point to any *common* misconfigurations.

Comment: i know man, i  appreciate u replying to my question, just wanted to mention it.

the thing is i have another service running an http app on another port and it behaves the same way, so definitely not nginx

Comment: You can delete your downvoted questions and answers to remove the negative rep associated with them. I got a lot of rep from answering questions in 2012-2015 that show up in some common google searches

Comment: sweet man guess i gotta find some common questions to answer then,
but the fun is in the not so common ones, like a puzzle game

Comment: You mention that it works on `wget http://localhost`. From the instance, also try accessing via the private IP address (eg `wget http://10.x.x.x`) and the public IP address (eg `wget http://1.2.3.4`). They will give hints as to where things might be blocked/denied. Also, when it fails, does it fail immediately, or does it take a while (eg 10+ seconds) before it fails? This will give a hint about connectivity.

Comment: That's actually a good idea, i tried the private address and it worked, but not with the public one, so maybe its a mapping issue ? it seems to fail immediately on multiple ports, but ssh is working ...

Comment: `reach the http website the first 2-3 minutes` and `ssh working` this is puzzling, the network setup is static, so I'd look at the server/software components. What runs on the server? Did you run out of memory?

Comment: i found the solution, some ports were blocked by AWS itself, their abuse team that is, this is what caused this weird behavior, had to pay 30usd for the developer plan to get this info cuz it wasnt apparent...

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this weird behavior was that AWS abuse team had blocked some of my ports, had to upgrade to the developer plan to be able to know this, contacting them at the moment